# WebView " website received notification" to Android Push notifications

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have set up a website to receive push notifications via one signal when the user receives a chat message on the site. The same site URL has been added to the Android web view and would like to know if it is possible to send webview "received notifications" as push notifications from the same android app?

Following is the mwebview code and sorry I am new to this.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);  // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.testsite.com/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```